# How to nest SCSS with "&" properly to re-use immediate parent (partial) class name?

Tags: css, sass, bem

I want to re-use the class name of the parent and use it on a child element, but it is not working as expected when nesting more than one level.
I want to concatenate the child class name only with the immediate parent string and not the whole concatenated parent.
I am starting to believe this is not possible.

The SCSS:

```
.block {
    margin: 2px;

    & &__element {
        margin: 3px;
              
        &-nested {
            margin: 4px;
        }
    }
}
```

The output:

```
.block {
  margin: 2px;
}

.block .block__element {
  margin: 3px;
}

.block .block__element-nested {
  margin: 4px;
}
```

The desired output:

```
.block {
  margin: 2px;
}

.block .block__element {
  margin: 3px;
}

.block .block__element .block__element-nested {
  margin: 4px;
}
```

Comment: Did you try: `.block {
    margin: 2px;

    & &__element {
        margin: 3px;
    
        &  &-nested {
                margin: 4px;
        }
    }
}` ? Like why do you set nested into a `&{ &-nested{}}` Like try `& &-nested{}`

Comment: Yes, I tried. But the result is: `.block .block__element .block .block__element-nested ` I would say, there is a `.block` too much in there.

Answer (score 1):

Bro, currently `nested-&` is not supported in **Sass**. Hopefully, that's the only solution:

```
.block {
  margin: 2px;

  & &__element {
    margin: 3px;
  }
  
  & &__element &-nested {
    margin: 4px;
  }
}
```

Comment: I hope somebody knows how to improve that, so there is no need to rewrite the `&__element`. Imagine the nesting goes deeper. Then this is not really different than wirting each class name out.

Comment: This answer actualy does not work as  the output of last is: `.block .block__element .block-nested`

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

To achieve your desired output you may do this.

```
      .block {
        margin: 2px;

        & &__element {
          margin: 3px;
        }

        & &__element &__element-nested {
          margin: 4px;
        }
      }
```

**EDIT 2**

```
      .block {
          margin: 2px;

          & &__element {
            margin: 3px;

              & .block__element-nested {
                  margin: 4px;
              }  
         }
      }
```

Output:

```
       .block {
         margin: 2px;
       }
       .block .block__element {
         margin: 3px;
       }
       .block .block__element .block__element-nested {
         margin: 4px;
       }
```

Comment: doesn't work, check here ... https://www.sassmeister.com/

Comment: I tried this already and the result is not as desired. See my EDIT. Thank you for the effort.

Comment: @alex351 - pls don't user personal answers, or pin-pointed in your `question`. That will only attract downvotes. You could have added your comment right below this answer.

Comment: @alex351 sorry... missed the extra `.block`. I've eedited my answer. Try that.

Comment: Hi @Becky . Yes, sorry, this is also what I tried. But actually I wanted to know, if I could improve this so I did not need to write &__element multiple times.

Comment: @alex351 I see. I don't think it is possible. What about replacing `& &__element &__element-nested {` with `& .block__element-nested {` ? I've added that to my answer. check **edit 2**

Comment: You can remove the & in the last selector. And no, this is just writing the selector out and not re-using the parent selector name. I didn't vote you down.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, your desired output doesn't make sense because it's very confusing on a larger scale. The bottom example is from the [docs](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/style-rules/parent-selector#adding-suffixes). The point is not to go deeper than the third level I think...

```
.block {
  background: red;

  &__element {
    background: red; 

    &--nested {
      background: red;
    }
  }
}

.block {
  background: red;
}
.block__element {
  background: red;
}
.block__element--nested {
  background: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here 2 solution that are working fine with the use of `selector-nest`.
You will find more information: https://sass-lang.com/documentation/modules/selector#nest

You can test solution here: https://www.sassmeister.com

### Method 1:

```
.block {
    margin: 2px;
      & &__element { 
        margin: 3px;
        
       #{selector-nest('.block__element', '&-nested')} {
            margin: 4px;
        }
    }
}
```

### Method 2:

```
.block {
    margin: 2px;
    
      #{selector-nest('.block', '&__element')}{
          margin: 3px;
          
          #{selector-nest('.block__element', '&-nested')} {
            margin: 4px;
        }
          
      }
}
```

Comment: This is a little similar to declaring a variable under .block (i.e.: $block: &;) And re-using #{$block} everywhere.

Comment: Quite, yes. The best but difference is you dont need to include it everywhere. you can start directly for this selector after

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this can not be done. As described here as well:
https://css-tricks.com/the-sass-ampersand/#what-the-isnt

> My intention was for the & to only get replaced with .parent in hopes of compiling to this:
> .parent .child {}
> But that doesn’t work.
> **The & is always the fully compiled parent selector.**